# Custom coefficient format for specific variable in fixest etable

Tags: r, fixest

I'm wondering if there's a way I can format the coefficient reported in `etable` in a customized way.

For example, in the below regression

```r
library(fixest)
feols(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width | Species, iris)
model_fit = feols(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width | Species, iris)
etable(model_fit)

                       model_fit
Dependent Var.:     Sepal.Length
                                
Sepal.Width     0.4959. (0.1206)
Petal.Length    0.8292* (0.0970)
Petal.Width     -0.3152 (0.1096)
Fixed-Effects:  ----------------
Species                      Yes
_______________ ________________
S.E.: Clustered      by: Species
Observations                 150
R2                       0.86731
Within R2                0.65201
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

I would like to multiply by 100 only to the coefficient of `Sepal.Width` for reporting and write a separate note for the adjustment, so that the `etable` report looks like

```r
                       model_fit
Dependent Var.:     Sepal.Length
                                
Sepal.Width     49.59 (0.1206)
Petal.Length    0.8292* (0.0970)
Petal.Width     -0.3152 (0.1096)
Fixed-Effects:  ----------------
Species                      Yes
_______________ ________________
S.E.: Clustered      by: Species
Observations                 150
R2                       0.86731
Within R2                0.65201
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Is there a handy way to achieve this in `fixest` `etable`?

Scaling `Sepal.Width` column and re-running the regression is the least preferable option for me.

Thank you.

Comment: only the coefficient? probably have to do it manually to object returned by `etable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

1. Create a helper function that takes as `x` one of the string entries in the object returned by `etable(model_fit)$model_fit` and uses a regular expression to extract the coeficient, multiply by `m=100`, and pastes it back into the original string `x`

```
f <- function(x,m=100) {
  coef = regmatches(x,regexec("^-?\\d+[.]?\\d+",x,perl=T))[[1]]
  paste0(as.numeric(coef)*m, gsub(coef,"",x))
}
```

2. assign `etable(model_fit)` to an object, `k`

```
k = etable(model_fit)
```

3. Now, use `f()` to change one a value in `k$model_fit`

```
k$model_fit[3] <- f(k$model_fit[3])
print(k)

                       model_fit
Dependent Var.:     Sepal.Length
                                
Sepal.Width      49.59. (0.1206)
Petal.Length    0.8292* (0.0970)
Petal.Width     -0.3152 (0.1096)
Fixed-Effects:  ----------------
Species                      Yes
_______________ ________________
S.E.: Clustered      by: Species
Observations                 150
R2                       0.86731
Within R2                0.65201
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```